# Is it possible to subscribe to TestCaseFinished and other events in xunit?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I would like to track the progress of a test run without modifying the actual runner. So the question is, can I subscribe to test case related events in xunit?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is not possible at the moment https://twitter.com/bradwilson/status/460974726890795008. I created an issue on GitHub so it can be tracked: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/76